# Call Postgres SQL stored procedure From Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am working on a Django Project with a Postgres SQL Database. I have written a stored procedure that runs perfectly on Postgres.

Now I want to call that stored procedure from Django 1.5 .. I have written the code but it prompts errors.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_save_message3(IN msg_sub character varying, IN msg_cont text, IN msg_type character varying, IN msg_category character varying, IN msg_created_by character varying, IN msg_updated_by character varying) RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$ DECLARE msg_id integer := 0;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_messages
        (message_subject, message_content, message_type, message_category, 
       created_on, created_by, updated_on, updated_by)
    VALUES 
      (msg_sub, msg_cont, msg_type, msg_category, LOCALTIMESTAMP, 
       msg_created_by, LOCALTIMESTAMP, msg_updated_by);
      Select into msg_id currval('tbl_messages_message_id_seq');
  return msg_id;
END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.fn_save_message(IN character varying, IN text, IN character varying, IN character varying, IN character varying, IN character varying)
  OWNER TO gljsxdlvpgfvui;
```

The Stored Procedure is Ok and it returns results.

```
c = connection.cursor()
    try:
        c.execute("BEGIN")
        c.callproc("fn_save_message", [Message_Subject, Message_Content, Message_Type, Message_Category, Created_By, updated_by])
        results = c.fetchone()
        c.execute("COMMIT")
    finally:
        c.close()
    print results
```

After all your suggestion my program is finally working. but one small issue left.

As i have used `results = c.fetchone()` to fetch the out parameters. 
it returns **(13,)**

but I only want to get **13** as a string or integer, how can I get only the value.

**Updated:**

the problem is solved using this

```
for item in results:
        message_id = item
```

Comment: Indentation problem? I'm not convinced this has anything to do with the SQL side at all. Separately, please *use placement parameters* rather than string concatenation; see http://bobby-tables.com/, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection, http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: Why wouldn't you run that code in the Django ORM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
c = connection.cursor()
try:
    c.execute("BEGIN")
    c.callproc("fn_save_message3", (Message_Subject, Message_Content, Message_Type, Message_Category, Created_By, Updated_By))
    results = c.fetchall()
    c.execute("COMMIT")
finally:
    c.close()
print results
```

You forgot the closing parens and were trying to call the functions on `cursor` instead of `c` and also had an issue with indentation. You should also use the `callproc()` function as documented [here.](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.callproc)

As catavaran said, you should read the documentation on executing custom SQL and use placeholders. Also, in Django 1.6+, the transactions are commited automatically so there is no need for `c.execute("COMMIT")`

Comment: As you said, i have update my code, now the different error arise, see the question now i have updated. it should accept the inputting argument because i no where define at it accept at most 2 arguments.

Comment: @MuhammadTaqiHassanBukhari Updated the answer. the new error means that the callproc() method expects 2 arguments instead of 7. http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.callproc

Answer (score 1):

```
    c = connection.cursor()
    try:
        c.execute("BEGIN")
        c.callproc("fn_save_message3", [Message_Subject, Message_Content, Message_Type, Message_Category, Created_By, updated_by])
        results = c.fetchone()
        c.execute("COMMIT")
    finally:
        c.close()
    for item in results:
        message_id = item
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing closing parenthesis at the `c.execute("SELECT fn_save_message3(...` line.  Add `)` after last quote symbol.

But anyway it is a wrong method of executing SQL from python code.  You should use placeholders to prevent sql injection attacks. [Read the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) with examples of the proper use of SQL in django.