# Call Postgresql procedure from Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, stored-procedures, procedure

I am using Postgresql in Django and Python,and I do all the CRUD operation successfully but I don't know how can I call Postgresql procedure from Django and show the result in my web application!!

Answer (score 0):

This should be completed using Django's ORM (Object Relational Mapper) querysets which is a Django wrapper that adds a layer of abstraction above an SQL query that retreives a given dataset from PostgreSQL (or another supported database).

Indeed, the existence of this layer is in place for security reasons in addition to enabling a developer to use any of the supported underlying databases (SQLite3, PostgreSQl, MySQL, Oracle or Maria DB (Django 3.0+)) by simply switching out the database credentials and settings.

The rendering of the datasets will be completed with either Django's templating system if you're usind Django across the entire stack. It could also be completed by creating APIs and using a front-end framework to render from them.

You should Google `Django ORM and Datasets` for further information, documentation and tutorials to achieve this.

Comment: I just want to call my procedure in Postgresql by Django , and it is not about Django ORM and dataset

Comment: Sorry, I thought you just meant a dataset. Have you tried looking at this? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819151/call-postgres-sql-stored-procedure-from-django)

Comment: OK. I think people will require a bit more detail about the specifics of what you're trying to achieve then. Have you got any code that you can share as part of your question? What error message came up, etc?